# is it safe/practical to control this 30A+ motor with mosfet?

Tags: induction-motor, high-current, powermosfet

I'm thinking of controlling a few high ampere water pumps from microchips.
the current draws of motors will be around 38A (single phase 220V motors).
is it safe to use a MOSFET (IPW60R070C6 from Infineon, [Datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2jLayk7nwAhUQV8AKHY0fD0IQFjABegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infineon.com%2Fdgdl%2FInfineon-IPW60R070C6-DS-v02_01-en.pdf%3FfileId%3Ddb3a30432313ff5e01232862aa644ac5&usg=AOvVaw1aUO4m9Sto1BDcXZYH9XrT)) for this purpose ? (assuming a well designed thermal solution w/ heat-sinks for mosfets)
the mosfet ratings seem OK (600V, 53A) and the motors will be on for ~2 hours continuously per day.

if this is safe why using SSR and other mechanical heavy-duty relays is common ?

Comment: 99.99% of all discrete MOSFETs (and 100% of all discrete power MOSFETs) have an anti-parallel parasitic diode so can only block current in one direction. Therefore, a single MOSFET on its own cannot be used to switch AC. You need multiple MOSFETs back to back and the associated support circuitry, which gives you one possible variation of a solid state relay.

Comment: thanks. what would be the "associated circuitry" called? I can search that.

Comment: Floating gate drive circuitry.

Comment: You can buy the MOSFETs and associated circuitry wrapped up in a convenient package ... called an SSR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those transistors *could* be used to control your water pumps.  But it's probably going to be a lot of work.

The problem is that while the Vds is rated to 600V, the Vgs is only rated to 30V max.  So, you're going to have some fairly complex drive circuitry to make that work.  And your load is both inductive and beefy--so heat sinking is going to be required.

The other solid-state way of dealing with AC switching like this is called a Triac.  Those might be more cost effective and possibly easier to deal with.

However, you're probably going to be better off getting something like a Crydom D2450 Solid State Switch.  http://www.crydom.com/en/products/panel-mount/perfect-fit/ac-output/series-1/d2450/

Those are about $40 each and Crydom already did the nasty engineering work to deal with mains voltages.

Or, you could just get a relay for $10 (about the price of your original transistor):
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electric-works/ADJH22005/7537064

Good luck.

Comment: Or thyristors. TRIACs are a poor man's thyristor. Triacs conduct and block in both directions, while thyristors block in both directions but only conduct in one so you need two anti-parallel for AC conduction. Triacs exist to reduce cost by mashing two thyristors together for AC but the result is assymetrical silicon and assymetrical behaviour. Also, they tend to be less rugged and smaller than thyristors. Also, thyristors and triacs latch on though and cannot interrupt current and turn themselves off. They do turn off if current in them goes to zero, but cant cause that to happen themselves.